# ASP.NET Core 1.1 User Impersonation with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, impersonation, asp.net-core-1.1, asp.net-core-identity

Stuck with lack of information when trying to implement a feature for user impersonation with .Net Core's Identity. I am trying to make [this ASP.NET MVC 4.6 code](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/) work in ASP.NET Core, but faced with some lines of codes which .NET Core no longer supports.

So below is the original 4.6 code to pass in `userName` and sign-in as the user.

```
public async Task ImpersonateUserAsync(string userName)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    var originalUsername = context.User.Identity.Name;

    var impersonatedUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

    var impersonatedIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(impersonatedUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserImpersonation", "true"));
    impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("OriginalUsername", originalUsername));

    var authenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication; 

    authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, impersonatedIdentity);
}
```

I've made it up to here, but stuck with `context.GetOwinContext().Authentication` part where I need to sign-out with the current cookie, and sign-in with this new user.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ImpersonateUserAsync(string userName)
{
    var originalUsername = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

    var impersonatedUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

    var impersonatedIdentity = await _userManager.CreateAsync(impersonatedUser);
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(impersonatedUser, new Claim("UserImpersonation", "true"));
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(impersonatedUser, new Claim("OriginalUsername", originalUsername));

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Has anyone done with this kind of approach?

Comment: Do you realise that `_userManager.AddClaimAsync` is adding the impersonation claims to the database, not just to the cookie? so every time you login with this user this impersonation claim will be on (unless you remove it from the DB when you de-impersonate)

Comment: That's a good point trailmax. As you can see in the link, they are used for detecting whether someone is doing impersonation and used to de-impersonate the user back into admin rights. I should remove them when I de-impersonate. Thanks.

Comment: @trailmax Didn't realize it was you whom wrote about impersonation in the link. Hi Trailmax. That is certainly an excellent approach. But things have changed when it comes to .Net Core. `SignIn` does not take `var impersonatedIdentity` anymore.  `SignIn` now can only take `ClaimsPrincipal`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpContext.Authentication`.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ImpersonateUserAsync(string userName) {
    var context = HttpContext; //Property already exists in Controller

    var originalUsername = context.User.Identity.Name;

    var impersonatedUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

    var impersonatedIdentity = await _userManager.CreateAsync(impersonatedUser);
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(impersonatedUser, new Claim("UserImpersonation", "true"));
    await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(impersonatedUser, new Claim("OriginalUsername", originalUsername));

    var authenticationManager = context.Authentication; 
    var cookie = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie;
    await authenticationManager.SignOutAsync(cookie);
    await authenticationManager.SignInAsync(cookie, impersonatedIdentity, 
        new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false });

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Reference Documentation [Using Cookie Middleware without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie#creating-an-identity-cookie)

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, I guess `HttpContext.Authentication` is the way to go, but `SignInAsync` fails to take `impersonatedIdentity`, the parameter can only take `ClaimsPrincipal` instead. Would you be able to do any workaround for this?

Comment: Figured out that `impersonatedIdentity` is used to find out whether identity operation has succeeded or not. So I don't think that line of code has nothing to do with `SignInAsync`. So my point is, how can `SignInAsync` be correctly used to sign-in(impersonation) with the user account which is stored in `AspNetUsers` table?

Comment: Create a claims principle and populate it with the necessary claims then sign in

Comment: Perhaps I can create a list of Claims `var claims` like `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, impersonatedUser.FirstName, ClaimValueTypes.String)`, `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, impersonatedUser.Email, ClaimValueTypes.String)` and pass it to `ClaimsPrincipal` like `var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));` But I believe it is not "actually" logged in as that user account? looks like it is faking it. I want admin to actually logged in as a user account so admin can see that user's assigned privileges across pages.

Comment: Doesn't `_userManager.CreateAsync` create a new user? And then `AddClaimAsync` is storing claims for that new user?